# Agora not working with capture card input

Tags: unity-game-engine, capture, agora.io

I am using agora unity sdk for one of my unity application. Its working fine with normal camera input but i want to use capture card as video input but agora not supporting capture card input. Is there way to do this .

Answer (score 0):

It seems the same question also posted on our slack channel. Here is a reference for further updates:
[Agora not working with capture card input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62150947/agora-not-working-with-capture-card-input)

In summary, two recommendations:

1. do a mapping from the capture card to a videocam.
2. consider capture raw video following this advanced guide: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/raw_data_video_unity?platform=Unity